# Rspec describe method syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I don't find syntax of Rspec `describe` method, but find some examples. If I correctly understand, we can pass into `describe` method a string, a class name (model name, for example), and a string and class name together as a parameters. What difference between these three cases of invocation `describe`?

```
describe 'string' do
...
end

describe ModelName do
...
end

describe 'string', ModelName do
...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on thing you want to describe.

That description is for you and other developers working with that code base.

```
$ rspec --format=documentation spec/
```

or just

```
$ rspec -fd spec/
```

will out

```
string
  ...
ModelName
  ...
string ModelName
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not a heavily used feature (admittedly in my limited experience), but `describe` can feed `subject` if provided with a module or class name (or presumably other objects under test)

```
class Foo
end

describe Foo do
  it "should be a Foo" do
    subject.should be_a Foo
  end
end
```

In the above example, which passes, giving `describe` a class name has caused it to return `Foo.new` from `subject`. Whereas passing the string `"Foo"` would not work the same way.

---

Another example:

```
describe  [], "an empty array" do
  it "should return nil from any index" do
    subject[1].should be_nil
  end
end
```

Running it:

```
$ rspec -f d rspec_describe.rb

[] an empty array
  should return nil from any index

Finished in 0.00255 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: It seems this is not recommended though: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/7c5d508bebf64c7f00b9d7d63ad1114ef481914c/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L36